# Failed to apply Hibernate Gradla plugin

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I have a Kotlin based Spring Boot project with Hibernate. I use Gradle (version 7.4.2) as a build tool for the project. When I try to apply Hibernate plugin as follows, I end up with the below issue. All others plugins work fine. I have also tried different versions without any luck.

**build.gradle**

```
...

plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "3.0.2"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.1.0"
    id "org.hibernate.orm" version "6.1.6.Final"

    ...

}
```

Gradle build output:

```
Build file '/xyz/build.gradle' line: 11

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.hibernate.orm', version: '6.1.6.Final']
> Failed to apply plugin 'org.hibernate.orm'.
   > Could not create an instance of type org.hibernate.orm.tooling.gradle.HibernateOrmSpec.
      > Extension of type 'JavaPluginExtension' does not exist. Currently registered extension types: [ExtraPropertiesExtension, SpringBootExtension, StandardDependencyManagementExtension, SourceSetContainer]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error usually shows up when a *plugin dependency* is missing.

Try adding the [Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html):

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I do not know why I thought Java plugin was applied by default.